# How to display only AMI id returned by boto3 instance.create_image()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, ec2-ami

Below is a boto3 code to create an ami from the given ec2 instance.
How can I modify the output to extract only the value of the created AMI id ?

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instance = ec2.Instance('xxxxxxxxxxx')
image = instance.create_image(
                BlockDeviceMappings=[
                {
                    'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
                    'Ebs': {
                        'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                    }
                }
            ],


        Name='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
)
image.wait_until_exists('self',Filters=[{'Name':'state','Values':['available']}])
print("Image Created ",image)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Image Created  ec2.Image(id='ami-0c59fddbexxxxxxxxxx')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `id`  to get the ami id alone:

```
#Boto3 code to create an ami from ec2 instance
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('yourec2id')
image = instance.create_image(
                BlockDeviceMappings=[
                {
                    'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
                    'Ebs': {
                        'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                    }
                }
            ],
        Name='yourec2id'
)
image.wait_until_exists('self',Filters=[{'Name':'state','Values':['available']}])
print("Image Created ",image.id)
```

Output:

```
Image Created  ami-xxxx
```